# How to create a show more/less button which applies to individual element with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There is an option to display `more` text, or `less`, but the `@click` event applies for the all `elements` and the all elements display all text.

I understand, that I need to pass some value to identify individual element, that the value would not apply to all elements, but at the moment stuck and would appriciate help.

HTML:

```
        <tr v-for="script in scripts.slice(0, 5)">
            <td>{{script.key}}</td>
            <td v-if="!readMore">{{script.script_content.substring(0, 200) + ".."}}</td>
            <td v-if="readMore">{{script.script_content}}</td>
            <button @click="showMore" v-if="!readMore" class="btn btn-primary">Show more</button>
            <button @click="showLess" v-if="readMore" class="btn btn-primary">Show less</button>
        </tr>
```

Vue data and methods:

```
data: () => ({
       readMore: false,
    }),
    methods: {
        showMore() {
            this.readMore = true;
        },
        showLess() {
            this.readMore = false;
        },
```

Array values:

[image]

How could I make a method apply only for an individual element?

In this situation, there is no need to create a component, because this case will be used only on one page.

Comment: Try creating only one `<td>` and one button with `toggle()` function onclick, which change text version to display, (full or cut)

Comment: Thanks. Could you make an example with jsfiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an object to hold a hash of `readMore` toggles, one for each item:

```js
data: () => ({
    readMore: {},
}),
```

The keys will be the item id.  Test those in the template and also set them in the buttons by passing that id:

```html
<td v-if="!readMore[script.id]">{{script.script_content.substring(0, 200) + ".."}}</td>
<td v-if="readMore[script.id]">{{script.script_content}}</td>
<button @click="showMore(script.id)" v-if="!readMore[script.id]" class="btn btn-primary">Show more</button>
<button @click="showLess(script.id)" v-if="readMore[script.id]" class="btn btn-primary">Show less</button>
```

And set values in `methods` by passing the item id and toggling it:

```js
methods: {
    showMore(id) {
        this.$set(this.readMore, id, true);
    },
    showLess(id) {
        this.$set(this.readMore, id, false);
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: "ReferenceError: Vue is not defined" when clicking on a button.

Comment: Oops, use `this.$set`

Comment: Toggles all the elements still.

Comment: Fixed it! The value passed in the methods should have been an ID, not the key, because there are keys that have the same value. Thanks again!

Comment: Edit the answer and replace key with an ID, and I will mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: Alright, edit your question to show that it has an ID :)

Comment: Edited. Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks, same to you

Answer (score 1):

Use index instead of this.$set

```
data: () => ({
   readMore: [false],
}),


methods: {
    showMore(index) {
  this.readMore[index] = true;
},
showLess(index) {
  this.readMore[index] = false;
},    



<tr v-for="(script,index) in scripts.slice(0, 5)">
        <td>{{script.key}}</td>
        <td v-if="!readMore[index]">{{script.script_content.substring(0, 200) + ".."}}</td>
        <td v-if="readMore[index]">{{script.script_content}}</td>
        <button @click="showMore(index)" v-if="!readMore[index]" class="btn btn-primary">Show more</button>
        <button @click="showLess(index)" v-if="readMore[index]" class="btn btn-primary">Show less</button>
    </tr>
```